# Як називати колишнього в'язня-злочинця

Tags: вибір-слова

Як можна називати людну, що скоїла злочин, відсиділа, і тепер на волі?

Якщо сказати *колишній [в'язень](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%27%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C)*, то чи тут чітко зрозуміло чому і ким він був ув'язнений? Які є інші варіанти?

Answer (score 4):

Існує жаргонізм - [зек](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53399/374574.html)

> - (-а) ч.; крим., жрм. [Ув'язнений](http://sum.in.ua/s/Uv.jaznenyj). <...> прийшов "зек" з колонії -    хтозна, що скажуть, що ми з ним водимось, тут і так на нас око    міліції (Ю. Покальчук, Те, що на споді). * У порівн. Щирого злота  зливок - талант! / (Мила природа, як зек, в поколіннях, в проточних   водах...) (О. Забужко, Диригент Останньої свічки). БСРЖ, 222; СЖЗ, 46; ЯБМ, 1, 384.
> - З рос.: зек (зэка), що становить скорочення слова заключенный -    зэка з наступною втратою а. ТСРОЖ, 65.

Російською теж, зек - людина, що ув'язнена і **відбуває** покарання. Але народ не робить різниці між минулим і поточним статусом, бо "колишніх зеків не буває"

Є старе та точне слово [каторжник](http://sum.in.ua/s/katorzhnyk)

> 1. Людина, яку заслано на каторгу або яка перебуває **чи була на каторзі**. Тихий кайдановий брязкіт змовк коло Петру ні, і до його
>      схиляється висхле з тонкими та довгими козацькими усами лице отамана
>      неволі, паторжника Кошового (Степан Васильченко, II, 1959, 53);
>      Каторжники в минулому, підпільники, пролетарі, селяни, матроси, вони
>      присвятили себе єдиній справі — добути народові щастя (Олесь Гончар,
>      II, 1959, 417); Роз'їждженим шляхом, під дощем, ішли відшмагані
>      різками каторжники з Верхівні. Блискавки освітлювали їм путь. Жандарми
>      їхали верхи (Натан Рибак, Помилка.., 1956, 265).
> 2. лайл. Злодій, негідник. — Ви не грек, а якийсь дезертир з Афона, а може, й каторжник, пройдисвіт! — лаявся Палладій через поріг
>      (Нечуй-Левицький, III, 1956, 393).

Відповідно підходять різною мірою [синонімі](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/k/katorzhanin/33-1-0-7775):

> колодник, кайданник, сибіряка, як ім. штемпований, іст. галерник;
>   (колишній або збіглий) з. варнак; пор. НЕВІЛЬНИК, В'ЯЗЕНЬ.

Єдина проблема, що усі ці синонімі, як власне і слово каторжник, старі і маловживані у наш час.

Comment: «[Зек](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=200330&page=1135)» і «[каторжник](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=40981&page=1295)» також є в новішому (2010–…) «Словнику української мови» — просто для інформації.

Comment: Пишуть що "Зек" походить від скорочення "з/к", яке у свою чергу означає "заключённый каналоармеец" - так називали людей що будували Беломорканал (пишуть наприклад тут: http://www.bibliotekar.ru/gulag/57.htm).

Comment: @Artemix, хм, я вважав, що це від «заключённый колонии» — але справді, «заключённый каналоармеец» розглядають, як надійнішу версію (виходить, «заключённый колонии» — народна етимологія або бекронім).

Answer (score 4):

Можна використати **відсид** чи **відсида**. Хоча *відсида* можна сприйняти як людину, що відсиджується. P.Vovk запропонував альтернативу **відсидько**.

Якщо підійти з іншого боку, то можна сказати, що бувший в'язень це **бувз**. Мені найбільше подобається саме *бувз*.

Answer (score 2):

Пропоную альтернативний варіант на основі вже усталеної в традиції перекладу і кіно в цілому форми:

- [Той, хто біжить по лезу](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%B9,_%D1%85%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83)
- [Той, хто гасить світло](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%B9,_%D1%85%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE)
- [Той, хто йде у вогні](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%B9,_%D1%85%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5_%D1%83_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BD%D1%96)
- [Той, хто пройшов крізь вогонь](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%A5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8C)

Отже, маємо декілька дієслів та іменників, котрі позначають людину або дію людину, яка колись сиділа у в’язниці:

1. [Відсиджувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidsydzhuvaty) - третє значення.
2. [Відбувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidbuvaty) - друге підзначення у першому значенні.
3. [Неволя](http://sum.in.ua/s/nevolja)
4. [В’язниця](http://sum.in.ua/s/v.jaznycja)

Тепер робимо лінґвістичний фокус:

1. Той, хто відсидів (ТХВ)
2. Той, хто відбув покарання (ТХВП)
3. Той, хто був у неволі (ТХБН)
4. Той, хто сидів у в’язниці (ТХСВ)

Мені здається, що коли вже *Той, хто біжить по лезу* прижився, то чому б не прижитися таким формулам? Тут допоможе й відома лінґвістична формула *Той-Кого-Не-Можна-Називати* з Гаррі Поттера.

Маємо:

1. Він - той, хто відсидів. (Або ТХВ, а потім пояснюємо людині, яка ще не знає скорочення)
2. Вона - та, хто відбула покарання.
3. Він - той, хто був у неволі.
4. Вона - та, хто сиділа у в’язниці.

Якщо можете замінити конструкцію в реченні, то можна просто казати:

1. Він відсидів.
2. Вона відбула покарання.
3. Він був у неволі декілька років.
4. Вона сиділа у в’язниці за дрібний злочин.

Ще декілька варіантів, до яких додумався спільний розум у коментах: відсид, відсидько.

Comment: Дуже цікава ідея, +1. А якщо спробувати щось на кшталт *відсид*, чи може, щоб для обом статям пасувало - *відсида*?

Comment: @Yola, дуже подобається ця ідея («відсид»).

Comment: @Yola а як вам "відсидько"?

Comment: @Sasha а вам як?

Comment: @P.Vovk, мені воно сприймається, як щось лагідніше чи кепкувальніше, ніж «відсид». Типу, як старенький дідок, що через якісь перепитії (можливо, навіть помилки системи) півжиття за ґратами провів, але загалом, незважаючи на це, некривдний, доброзичливий і якось намагається прилаштуватися до суспільного життя (і іноді навіть по-доброму смішний через не завжди вдалі спроби цього) — відсидько; а як двохметровий амбал, що вже через два тижні після виходу зґвалтував дівчину, розгамселив магазин і скалічив його похилого віку охоронця — відсид.

Comment: Відсид — нейтральне, можливо, холодно-нейтральне. Відсидько — зменшувальне, з підтекстом відсутності небезпеки від нього, можливо, навіть з кепкуванням чи навпаки співчуттям.

Comment: @Sasha тоді відсид буде для тих, хто справді зробив щось недобре, а відсидько - хто по дурості потрапляє до неволі постійно. "Хто, цей? Так, цей відсидько нещодавно вийшов, але з його вдачею скоро знов залетить."

Comment: @P.Vovk, я б сказав: «відсид» — нейтральний варіант за замовчуванням (коли не знаєш, за що сидів, наскільки винуватий, що за людина), а «відсидько» — вже з особливою конотацією (незагрозливості, лагідності чи кепкування). Бо не кожен відсид заслуговує, щоб його називали відсидьком, а від деяких ще й по хребтині можна отримати за недоречну зменшувальну форму (ну, це моє припущення; може, в справнього в'язня навпаки, незрозуміле «відсид» асоціюватиметься з якоюсь образою, а незрозуміле «відсидько» він сприйматиме нейтральніше).

Comment: Вчора дружина зауважила, що *відсида* може ще асоціюватись із людиною яка відсиджується.

Comment: @Sasha а якщо піти з іншого боку і сказати, що бувший в'язень це **бувз**?

Comment: @Yola або був’яз.

Comment: @Yola, якщо чесно, не дуже розумію, що стоїть за «бувз».

Comment: @Sasha **був**ший **в**'я**з**ень. Не обов'язково, щоб було надто зрозуміло, у зека теж а випало.

Comment: @Yola, ну але «зек» склалося саме (чи, можливо, під впливом тогочасних керівників). До власних неологізмів, стоворених людиною, що не є суперзіркою та не має тисяч підлеглих, світ застосовує жорсткіші критерії. (А «відсид»/«відсида»/«відсидько» — цілком самозрозуміле, по-моєму, може й пройти.)

Comment: бувший - це росіянізм, краще колишній в'язень - колв, або колв'яз